# Don't break the build - how?

Tags: svn, maven, version-control, build, build-process

Here are the steps I always follow before checking in the code,

1. Get the latest from svn
2. Merge conflicted files
3. Build
4. Run my tests
5. Check-in

In spite of all this, there is still a chance that I might break the build, if there are any local changes that I might have missed checking in. I know that having a Continuous Integration server would solve this once and for all. But it's a new project and CI server has not been setup yet.

Here are some of the useful articles I read on the topic.

- [Don't break the build](http://nathanbrixius.wordpress.com/2011/01/07/dont-break-the-build/)
- [Version control habits of good developers](http://sitaramc.github.com/tips/1-vc-habits.html)

Any advice on how to absolutely make sure that I don't break the build?

Comment: Despite your best efforts and all your precautions, there's always a chance you can forget something and screw up a build. Just like there is a chance of a system being compromised, despite it's high level of security.
The maven release plugin has a `prepare` goal which (among other things) checks if you've committed all your local changes (even to files which you still haven't added under your version control). I am not sure if this will suit your needs. I know it will change at least two files and that you'll need to keep in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't such mechanism in Maven. It's your business what you're doing after build and what you check-in. Even with CI you can do anything you want, you just know quite early you broke a build. It doesn't prevent you from doing wrong, it just provide quick feedback. However, when  you try to do release with Maven (using `maven-release-plugin`) it will then check if there are some uncommited changes, so you can be sure that your release-related build is OK and this is really important. But with just a regular build it's not so critical, in my opinion.

Comment: What makes it really important for me to make sure that the build is good every time I check-in, is the fact that I work in a distributed team and if I make a mistake and go home, someone on the other side of the world has a real bad day trying to fix my code.

Comment: Well, in this case simply install a CI server. If this is an open source project, you can get free Jenkins hosting for your github project from cloudbees.com.

Comment: So introduce Continues Integration. Even at your localhost if you can't do it within your project's infrastructure (but it's just a few minutes in fact). As I said, I don't believe there is a tool that force you to check-in all stuff that is need to successful build. Get Jenkins, set it up in few minutes and configure so it uses its own SVN workspace.

Answer (score 2):

> In spite of all this, there is still a chance that I might break the
>   build, if there are any local changes that I might have missed
>   checking in

You can check your working copy by `svn status` command after commit. This will reduce the chance to forget something to add and commit to repository.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't an easy way to make sure. You can always make a mistake when committing. These rules help minimize the risk

- Make a habit of "always committing everything", I.e. don't keep local changes and never work on two tasks in the same working copy.
- Before committing, check for unversioned files.
- Keep the build process identical on the build server and developer machines.